# Difference between updated_parsed and published_parsed with feedparser in Python

Tags: python, feedparser

I'm using feedparser and it seems that for a vast majority of feed items have a `published_parsed` field. However, some others only have an `updated_parsed` field.

How do I know when to use one or the other? Am I safe if I use either one or the other, something like this?

```
def get_publishing_date(item):
    try:
        return item.published_parsed
    except:
        return item.updated_parsed
```

Does `feedparser` not offer this abstraction itself?

Answer (score 1):

After a bit more investigation I found out this in the documentation:

> Note: As of version 5.1.1, if `feed.updated` key doesn’t exist but `feed.published` does, the value of `feed.published` will be returned.

Thus, it seems that one could rely only on `feed.updated`, respectively `feed.updated_parsed` to do the work.